# jQuery UI dialog dialogExtend maximize; enter browser fullscreen mode and maximize dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog, fullscreen

I am trying to automatically enter the browser's fullscreen mode when the user clicks on 'maximize' within a jQuery UI dialog, extended with dialogExtend (which provide standard maximize/minimize functionality to a jQuery UI dialog).

I am using the following code within the beforeMaximize event:

```
"beforeMaximize": function () {
    //alert("before");
    var elem = this.element;
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
        elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
        elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
        elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
        elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
}.bind(this)
```

("this" within bind(this) refers to the jquery UI dialog object.)

If I am debugging and stepping through all the steps of the if..then blocks, none of them gets to true.

Web browser is current google chrome.

I have tried also with:

- var elem = this;
- var elem = this.element.parent;

to no avail.

how to enter the browser into fullscreen mode when clicking on 'maximize' within a jQuery dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer myself: I had to set 
`var elem = document.body`
instead of trying to set the elem to the jQuery dialog.